# how can i send a postman request to a url in json with python

Tags: json, python-3.x, postman

Hello there i have made a api which tests if a telegram bot is dead or alive we need to send json data through post

Json Data is

```
{
username:@testbot
}
```

How can i send the request with python?

Answer (score 0):

Postman UI has great UX design ,its self explanatory:

[image]

1. in your case goto body , select json from the drop down
2. Paste your json body make sure you enclose key and value with double quotes as shown
3. Choose http method, and set the url
4. Click send ,